# Fill Android Facebook Dialog With App Data?

Tags: java, android, facebook, sdk, fill

I've been working with the Facebook Android SDK for the past couple days, and while I have been able to post to my wall, one thing still stumps me:  How can I fill the wall post dialog with information from my app?

For example, say you had an app that recorded hiking distance.  When I launched the stream.publish dialog, I would want the text area under "What's on your mind?" to say something like "[User] hiked [distance] miles" instead of being blank.

I looked through the two samples included in the SDK, but neither address this. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you publish an attachment like - `parameters.putString("attachment", publishingAttachment())`

To add a message, just add the following line - `parameters.putString("message", messageString);`